# Check numeric value in javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers

I read online tutorial it states: 
Actually, the most reliable conversion check is either a regexp or isNumeric below:

```
function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n)
}
```

My question is why this function can not be simplified to:

```
  function isNumeric(n) {
      return isFinite(n)
  }
```

Comment: is it not required because if n is undefined it will result in a reference error

Comment: So it can be simplified right? I find the tutorial is on http://javascript.info/tutorial/number-math

Comment: @Niko ah I misunderstood the problem (just thought check the input as number).

Comment: @bean You should maybe include some kind of input->output specification in your question to make clear for what exactly your function should test.

Comment: @Niko thanks, I will add them next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is why this function can not be simplified to:
>
> ```
> function isNumeric(n) {
>    return isFinite(n)
> }
> ```

It can't, no, you want that `parseFloat` in there if there's any chance `n` may not be a number to start with. But it could be simplified to:

```
function isNumeric(n) {
    return isFinite(parseFloat(n));
}
```

...because `isFinite(NaN)` is false, which is what your function returned for unparseable numbers anyway.

It's worth noting that `parseFloat` will stop at the first invalid character and return whatever number it found up to that point, so `parseFloat("123abc")` is `123`, not `NaN`. If you want to validate that the entire string can be correctly parsed as floating point, use `+` or `Number()`:

```
function isNumeric(n) {
    return isFinite(+n); // Or: return isFinite(Number(n));
}
```

Now, if you know for sure that `n` will **always** already be a number (not a boolean or a string or something), then yes, you could skip the parsing stage.

Answer (score 2):

Because isFinite(n) will return true for non-numeric values, for example:

```
alert(isFinite(false)); // displays true
```

Comment: `NaN` is a non-numeric value but `isFinite(NaN)` returns false.

Comment: It's maybe just that the word "for **some** non-numeric values" is missing here (as there only needs to be a single legal input that leads to the wrong output to invalidate the approach).

Answer (score 0):

Well no you can't use is finite as that will only return true for a finite number.

For example `isFinite(1/0)` returns false.

Infinity is a number its just not finite.

I'd suggest looking at how the big libraries do it for example:

**Jquery**

```
isNumeric: function( obj ) {
// parseFloat NaNs numeric-cast false positives (null|true|false|"")
// ...but misinterprets leading-number strings, particularly hex literals ("0x...")
// subtraction forces infinities to NaN
   return obj - parseFloat( obj ) >= 0; 
}
```

**Underscore.js**

```
function isNumber(obj) {
   return toString.call(obj) == '[object Number]';
}
```